# How to replace key names in a json file without making it a json array

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a script to replace a key name in a json file. Currently the json format of the file is:

```
{json:data1}
{json:data2}
{json:data3}
```

But whenever I run my script

```
import json

json_data = []
with open('test.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        asjson = json.loads(line)
        asjson['new_keyname'] = asjson.pop('old_keyname')
        json_data.append(asjson)

with open('result.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_data, file, indent=2)
```

It turns into a json array:

```
[{json:data1},{json:data2},{json:data3}]
```

How do I change the key name without changing the json format?

Comment: You turn it into array, thats your json_data variable, declare a dict and use update not append. Also your code about read/write json file is not a good way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `json_data` *is* an array itself, so it dumps to an array. Multi-line text is not a valid json format, but if that's what you want, try:

```
with open('result.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for x in json_data:
        f.write(json.dumps(x) + '\n')

# result.txt
{"k3": "v1"}
{"k3": "v2"}
{"k3": "v3"}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Any advice on what should I declare json_data as?

Comment: @SENTINELPROJECT I didn't quite follow your question. Doesn't this answer still not work?

Comment: Offf my bad, I thought I still have to change my initial json_data declaration. Works now thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your JSON looks invalid. I'm not quite sure what kind of data you want to represent, but at least you should use quotes, i.e.:

```
{"data1": "value1"}
```

With two key/value pairs, it would look like:

```
{"data1": "value1",
 "data2": "value2"}
```

Also, there's no need to parse one line at the time. Your code could look like this:

```
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

# change key data1 to key1
json_data['key1'] = json_data.pop('data1')

with open('result.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f, indent=2)
```

This will directly read the JSON into dict, change one key and write it back.

Comment: I think Json is double quoted.

Comment: @knh190 exactly

Comment: thanks for the advice, the reason why i wanted to parse it one at a time is because i is a collection of json lines, not one whole json so it contains multiple lines with that key i wanted to replace. My mistake on the quotes, i should have represented it clearer.

Comment: @SENTINELPROJECT ok, but I don't think you can have a "collection of JSON lines" in a single JSON file. The `json.load` parser will throw an error on such a file.